# How to stack a tensor of shape (n, k) with tensors of shape (k) in libtorch?

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

`torch::stack` accepts a `c10::TensorList` and works perfectly fine when tensors of the same shape is given. However, when you try to send the output of a previously `torch::stack`ed Tensor, it fails and gives memory access violation.

To be more concrete, let's assume we have 3 Tensors of shape 4 like:

```cpp
torch::Tensor x1 = torch::randn({4});
torch::Tensor x2 = torch::randn({4});
torch::Tensor x3 = torch::randn({4});
torch::Tensor y = torch::randn({4});
```

The first round of stacking is trivial:

```cpp
torch::Tensor stacked_xs = torch::stack({x1,x2,x3});
```

However, trying to do :

```cpp
torch::Tensor stacked_result = torch::stack({y, stacked_xs});
```

will fail.
I'm looking to get the same behavior as in `np.vstack` in Python where this is permitted and works.
How should I be going about this?

Comment: I couldnt come up with a better title! what could be a better title? please suggest so its more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a dimension to `y` with `torch::unsqueeze`. Then concatenation with `cat` (not `stack`, so different from numpy but the result will be what you ask for) :

```
torch::Tensor x1 = torch::randn({4});
torch::Tensor x2 = torch::randn({4});
torch::Tensor x3 = torch::randn({4});
torch::Tensor y = torch::randn({4});

torch::Tensor stacked_xs = torch::stack({x1,x2,x3});
torch::Tensor stacked_result = torch::cat({y.unsqueeze(0), stacked_xs});
```

It is also possible to flatten your first stack then reshape it, up to your preference :

```
torch::Tensor stacked_xs = torch::stack({x1,x2,x3});
torch::Tensor stacked_result = torch::cat({y, stacked_xs.view({-1}}).view({4,4});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. the second method seems like more practical to me . in any way really appreciate your time and kind response

Comment: trialNerror: The view solution doesnt seem to be working as it results in the following exception :```stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [4] at entry 0 and [12] at entry 1```

Comment: Yep small mistake, confused stack with cat, thanks for pointing it out. It works now :)